# how to fire a function on a jquery tab getting shown?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a jQuery tab set that I am using as a wizard. So you start with tab one's content, then when you click a button in tab one, you go to tab two and so on through the flow. The wizard flows will be dynamic so not all wizards will have the same steps.

In one wizard flow I have a payment screen I want to show. On showing the tab  I want to pull data from the previous tabs to build a shopping cart screen. How can I fire a function on the payment tab showing. I want this tab to be reusable for different transaction flows so I cant  rely on the panel before. I want to keep the event listening inside the payment panel.

Any suggestions on coding this, or possible plugins?

Comment: What ideas do you have so far? Show a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tie it to this event: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```